# Visual Studio 2022 - missing references - template engine

Tags: rhino3d

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w4Oe.png)

Hello,

I would like to write a script for Rhinoceros 3d, and therefore I need to download extension "RhinoCommon and Grasshopper templates for Rhino7".

But I can't, because of the missing references: Microsoft Visual Studio Template Engine. Take a look at screenshot in attachment.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install the Visual Studio SDK based on the VSIX Documentation:

> To use VSIX projects, you must install the Visual Studio SDK. For more information about the Visual Studio SDK, see Visual Studio SDK.

[VSIX Documetnation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix-project-template?view=vs-2022). [See VS SDK install instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/installing-the-visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2022).

This may be a result of an oversight by McNeal based on comments received by a developer who had similar errors being reported by some users but not most. [This service forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vsix-install-fails-visual-studio-template-engine-m/1025679#T-N1037086):

> You listed “Microsoft Visual Studio Template Engine” as a dependency. A dependency is the notion that your extension depends on another extension to be installed, and “Microsoft Visual Studio Template Engine” is not an extension. Are you perhaps trying to list it as a prerequisite? Prerequisites indicate which VS components need to be installed in order to support your extension.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on one grasshopper component development, and my current platform is Rhino7. The template for grasshopper Add-On for v6 is the one I am using, and it seems just fine.

- Where you can get the grasshopper Add-On for v7
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=McNeel.Rhino7Templates
- The people might faced the similar issue as you
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/295487/how-to-solve-missing-templates-in-visual-studio-en.html

By just quick search, I think reinstall the whole visual studio might be a practical apporach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but but found out I didn't have my visual studio setup the right way for Rhino development. Have you tried following this installation guide:
https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinocommon/installing-tools-windows/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).